# Всевозможные варианты из n-размерного масива JS

Tags: javascript

Есть масив который может содержать n количество масивов(в этом масиве может содержаться n количество елементов)
Пример

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14,15]]
```

Вопрос:
Как мне получить всевозможные значения из этого n-размерного масива:

Пример:

`[1,5,10],[1,5,11]...[1,5,15],[1,6,10],[1,6,11]....[2,5,10]`

Comment: Это называется [Cartesian Product](https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms/tree/master/src/algorithms/sets/cartesian-product) (там же пример для двух наборов). Пример для любого количества наборов можно посмотреть тут: https://github.com/mgechev/javascript-algorithms/blob/master/src/combinatorics/cartesianproduct.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Завел дополнительый массив длины `matrix.length` → `[0, 0, 0]` каждое число которого указывает на текущий индекс каждого массива внутри матрицы.

Для вашего примера, `[0, 0, 0] → [1, 5, 10]`, `[0, 0, 1] → [1, 5, 11]` и т.д.

Остается справа налево, в цикле увеличивать «ячейки» этого массива на 1.

```js
console.log = (e) => pre.append(JSON.stringify(e) + "\n");

let matrix = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
];

let index_list = new Array(matrix.length).fill(0);

loop: while (true) {
  console.log( index_list.map((index, row) => matrix[row][index]) );

  let i = index_list.length - 1;
  while (++index_list[i] >= matrix[i].length) {
    // Число в index_list[i] вышло за пределы очередного массива?
    index_list[i] = 0; // Обнулить
    i--; // Пусть на следующей итерации ++Увеличивается разряд слева.
    
    if (i == -1) break loop; // Всё перебрал.
  }
}
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```